# React Form Select Option with Two Hard-Coded Options (and the rest mapped)

Tags: html, reactjs

I'm relatively new-ish to front-end development (especially React).  I'm typically more of a back-end developer, but the other developers on my team have recently left the company, leaving me alone to try to better figure out the entire stack of our platform, which is written in React.

We have a form that has a select control.  In its current state, the control has an explicit default option (i.e. Select an Instructor), and the rest are mapped from a database table.  The default option is disabled and cannot be selected as an option.  It is really there for the default display (which is a speicfic Ux requirement for this story).  I've been tasked with adding an additiona option (i.e. Not Applicable) that allows the person filling out the form to select that option so they don't have to explicitly select a user's name.  This is what I've implemented for that Form control:

```
<Form.Group controlId="instructor">
   <Form.Label>{t("Primary Instructor")} - <em>{t("Optional")}</em></Form.Label>
   <Form.Control
      as="select"
      custom
      required
      disabled={!inputClass.CourseId}
      value={inputClass.InstructorId || ""}
      onChange={(e: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLTextAreaElement>) =>
         setInputClass({
            ...inputClass,
            InstructorId: e.target.value ? parseInt(e.target.value) : null
         })
      }
   >
      <option disabled key="empty" value="">
         {t("Select an instructor")}
      </option>
      <option key="empty" value="0">
         {t("Not Applicable")}
      </option>
      {instructors.map((instructor) => {
         if (selectedCourse) {
            if (selectedCourse.OnlineOnly || isCertifiedInstructor(instructor)) {
               return (
                  <option key={instructor.UserId} value={instructor.UserId}>
                     {instructor.FirstName} {instructor.LastName}
                  </option>
               );
             }
          }
       })}
    </Form.Control>
```

As you can see in the onChange event, it is evaluating the selected value, and if it is falsey, it is returning null.  If the selected value has an option, it is parsing it to an int and setting the state the form's model to that value for the InstructorId.  Ideally, I would like Select an Instructor to not be selectable, and have Not Applicable pass NULL back to the database when that is selected.  However, Select an Instructor and Not Applicable can't have the same value.  I attempted to set the Value for Not Applicable to 0, but obviously, the onChange event still evaluates "0" as falsey and so it returns null and the droplist option reverts back to "Select an Instructor".  I don't know what other value I can set that Not Applicable option to that will allow me to accomplish what I need to do.  I also attempted to use this in the onChange event:

```
onChange={(e: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLTextAreaElement>) =>
   setInputClass({
      ...inputClass,
      InstructorId: e.target.value || e.target.value == "0" ? parseInt(e.target.value) : null
   })
}
```

But it still seems to be returning null as the droplist is still reverting to the "Select an Instructor" option.

I guess my biggest problem here is that no matter what I put as a value for the "Not Applicable" option, it keeps reverting back to the "Select an Instructor" option when I select it. (on the client side, not when I submit it)

I realized it has to due with the value property I have set on the form control

```
value={inputClass.InstructorId || ""}
```

So I'm assuming that when Not Applicable is selected wtih a value of "0", it's evaluating it as falsey and defaulting to the "" option.

Does anyone have any other ideas on how to circumvent this defualt?

Answer (score 1):

I also favour backend and have to work with React at times, I know your pain.

JavaScript's type coercion is evaluating both `null` and `0` to `false`. So `inputClass.InstructorId || ""` will give you `""` in both scenarios. I've been caught out by this more times than I would like to admit.

You might have better luck with the [nullish coalescing operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Nullish_coalescing_operator). `inputClass.InstructorId ?? ""` will evaluate to `""` when `inputClass.InstructorId` is `null`, but **not** when it is `0`.